# Combine two expression in Bash

Tags: bash

I did check the ABS, but it was hard to find a reference to my problem/question there.

Here it is. Consider the following code (Which extracts the first character of `OtherVar` and then converts `MyVar` to uppercase):

```
   OtherVar=foobar
   MyChar=${OtherVar:0:1} # get first character of OtherVar string variable
   MyChar=${MyChar^} # first character to upper case
```

Could I somehow condense the second and third line into one statement?

P.S.: As was pointed out below, not needs to have a named variable. I should add, I would like to not add any sub-shells or so and would also accept a somehow *hacky* way to achieve the desired result.

P.P.S.: The question is purely educational.

Comment: No, you cannot nest parameter expansions because they take the form `$(var...}` if you attempt to nest the RESULT, you longer have a named `var` as the parameter. (e.g. `${${var:0:1}^}`) where `${var:0:1}` is the result, not a `var`. (which is why you didn't find any examples in ABS `:)` -- but good job for checking!

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment. I think I should add to the description above, that I do not want to spawn any sub-shells or so.

Comment: You don't -- that is why using parameter expansions are preferred -- they are built-in to bash `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it all-in-one without forking sub-shell or running external command:

```sh
printf -v MyChar %1s "${OtherVar^}"
```

Or:

```sh
read -n1 MyChar <<<"${OtherVar^}"
```

Another option:

```sh
declare -u MyChar=${OtherVar:0:1}
```

But I can't see the point in such optimization in a bash script.

There are more suitable text processing interpreters, like awk, sed, even perl or python if performance matters.

Comment: @stephanmg - `printf` is another built-in, so this is a very good option. You can actually check `man bash` (around line 3700) for `printf`

Comment: What is the problem with forking sub-shell?

Comment: Forking has cost in CPU. Need to copy all the parent shell environment, run a new process in it, then capture the output of the sub-shell: Pipes `|`, parenthesis or back-ticks `(cmd-list)`, `$(cmd-list)`, stream `< <(cmd-list)` all spawns a sub-shell.

Comment: I think this is a good solution, nevertheless, I want to stress, that there is absolutely no need to do this in one statement in general. Where would I find a description of `declare -u`?

Comment: @stephanmg See: `help declare`

Comment: @LéaGris, yes I assumed so, but for me it is now showing the `-u` option (OSX). I presume this will convert the first character to upper case on assignment. Will check later on my Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the cut command and put it in a complex expression to get it on one line, but I'm not sure it makes the code too much clearer:

```sh
OtherVar=foobar
MyChar=$(echo ${OtherVar^} | cut -c1-1) # uppercase first character and cut string
```